# Loopback 4: Create seeders to add dummy data in mySQL table

Tags: loopbackjs

I have been looking around option to create data seeders to add dummy data in my loopback 4 application. However I am not able to find any option in official documentation.

I have found couple of post but those refer to loopback 3, like:

1. [Loopback: Creating a Seed Script](https://medium.com/@joshuawootonn/loopback-creating-a-seed-script-a6e135fe5883)
2. [loopback-seed](https://www.npmjs.com/package/loopback-seed)

Please point me out to documentation to do so.

**EDIT:**

As per suggestion I have created start.js file in scripts folder:

```
require('babel-register')({
    presets: ['es2015']
})

module.exports = require('./seed.js')
```

And I have copied the script converting it to JavaScript mentioned in seed.js file. When I am running the script, I am getting error:

> Cannot find module Models and Repositories

though I have typed correct path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm doing it with Loopback directly like this (this is typescript):

```
import * as users from './users.json';

import * as Promise from 'bluebird';
import {Entity, DefaultCrudRepository} from '@loopback/repository';

import {MyApplication} from '../src/application';
import {User} from '../src/models';
import {UserRepository} from '../src/repositories';

const app = new MyApplication();

async function loadByModel<T extends Entity, ID>(items: T[], repository$: DefaultCrudRepository<T,ID>, type:  { new(it: Partial<T>): T ;}){
    console.log(type.toString());
    let repository = await repository$;
    await repository.deleteAll();
    await Promise.map(items, async (item: T) => {
        try{
            return await repository.create((new type(item)));
        } catch(e){
            console.log(item);
        }
    }, {concurrency: 50});
}

async function load(){
    await loadByModel(users, await app.getRepository(UserRepository), User);
}


app.boot().then(async () => {
    await load();
    console.log('done');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I am facing issue to run this script. How can I run these migrations?

Comment: What’s your error? If you’re not using Typecript, you should also convert it to plain Javascript.

Comment: When I am running js file like: `node server/seed`, its giving me error User module not found, even though I am adding the right path. And I have babel in place.

Answer (score 0):

We used a separate library [db-migrate](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to keep our migration and seed scripts out of our loopback codebase. Moreso, because db.migrate and db.update methods of juggler are not 100% accurate as mentioned in docs as well. [LB4 Database Migrations](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Database-migrations.html)